# ignore but recall malformed data : iterate & process folder with bash script + .jar

Tags: bash, jar, data-processing

There is a folder full of files- each of which contains some data that I need to convert to a single output file.

I've built a conversion script- it can run like so:

```
java -jar tableGenerator.jar -inputfile more-adzuna-jobs-type-9.rdf -skillNames skillNames.ttl -countries countries_europe.rdf -outputcsv out.csv
```

The problem is- some of the files contain characters that are regarded as invalid by my `.jar` file, is there a way to create a bash script to run this command simultaneously on a folder full of these files (many hundreds) and for each one that generates an error to:

- ignore it, i.e. not let it halt the process
- remember it- so that later it can be dealt with appropriately

It seems like this would be possible but my bash-fu is quite weak- what would be a logical way to execute this task?

Comment: If you're more familiar with Java, you could use Groovy instead of bash. Groovy supports Java syntax and you can run as a script via command line: `groovy script.groovy arg1 arg2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Java program in fact exits with an error status then it should be fairly easy to write a `bash` script that processes all the files in a folder and tracks which had errors.  I emphasize that the Java program must exit with an error (non-zero) status for this to be easy.  For example, it should terminate execution by invoking `System.exit(1)`.

If your program does report its success or failure to the system via its exit status, then you might do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The name of the directory to process is expected as the first argument.
if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo usage: $0 directory
  exit 1  
fi

# The first argument to the script is $1

if [ -e failures.txt ]; then
  rm failures.txt
fi

touch failures.txt

for f in $1/*; do
  if ! java -jar /path/to/tableGenerator.jar \
      -inputfile $f \
      -skillNames /path/to/skillNames.ttl \
      -countries /path/to/countries_europe.rdf \
      -outputcsv $f.out.csv
  then
    echo $f >> failures.txt
  fi
done
```

That iterates over all the files in the directory specified by the first script argument, assigning each path in turn to shell variable `$f`, and runs your Java program for each one, passing the path as the argument following `-inputfile`.  In the event that the program exits with a non-zero status, the script writes the name of the failing file in file `failures.txt` in the script's current working directory (unrelated to the data directory designated to it) and continues.

Note that it does not run the command simultaneously on all the files, but instead iteratively.  I am uncertain whether that was a key component of your request.  Inasmuch as the system you run this on is unlikely to have a separate core it can dedicate to each of hundreds of instances of your program, and inasmuch as the storage medium on which the files reside probably has only one data channel, you cannot effectively run the command hundreds of times simultaneously, anyway.

If you do want to run multiple jobs in parallel then `bash` has ways to do that, but I recommend getting the serial script working first.  If processing the files serially is not good enough then you can explore ways to achieve some parallelism.  However, to the extent that Java VM startup time may present an issue with starting up hundreds of JVMs, you might be better off building multiple-file handling directly into your Java program, so that you can process all the files in the same VM.

Comment: is it possible that `out.csv` is being overwritten every time- because the final output seems too small. also it seems not to have generated a file called `failures.txt`

Comment: I even created a file `failures.txt` and I'm pretty sure it `rm`'d it

Comment: Whether `out.csv` is overwritten is a function of your program.  The script I provided just passes that name as an argument.

Comment: hmm- is there a way to just increment the name of `out.csv` each time, and then maybe later I could put them all together?

Comment: As for `failures.txt`, remember that, as I wrote, it is created in the script's current working directory, which is not necessarily the data directory.  The script *does* `rm` `failures.txt` at startup, as you should be able to see.  That happens once, at startup, before processing any files, so that results from one run are not combined with results from a previous one.  You can certainly remove that bit if it doesn't suit you.

Comment: this time it leaves `failures.txt` but it doesn't write anything to it- it's totally blank

Comment: I updated the script just now, however, so that after removing `failures.txt` it creates an empty one.  If there are no failures, however, then nothing will be written to it.  NOTE WELL my comments about the Java program exiting with an error status in case of failure.

Comment: I have just updated the script to provide an `-outputcsv` argument for each run that is based on the name of the input file.  That's both easier and clearer than numbered output files.

Comment: The shell records the exit status of the last command it ran in the special variable `$?`.  Immediately after you run your program, you can run `echo $?` to print its exit status.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, `0` is a (the) success code for the shell's purposes.  The script does not record successful runs as failures.